# R lme4 Error in '/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession' : malloc(): memory corruption:

Tags: r, memory, error-handling, lme4

Whenever I run `lmer` or `glmer` from `lme4` package, I get the following error:

> Error in '/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession' : malloc(): memory
>   corruption:

I update all R packages but still getting the same error.

**sessionInfo()**

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lme4_1.1-13  Matrix_1.2-8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] minqa_1.2.4     MASS_7.3-45     tools_3.3.2     Rcpp_0.12.9     splines_3.3.2  
[6] nlme_3.1-131    grid_3.3.2      nloptr_1.0.4    lattice_0.20-34
```

**Edited**

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
```

Throws the following error:

> Error in '/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession' : malloc(): memory
>   corruption:

Comment: Can you use lme4 at all? Do the problems persist from the terminal (outside of rstudio)?

Comment: Yes,  I can load `lme4` library and can get help both in `RStudio` and `Terminal`. The error appears in the `Terminal` too.

Comment: I would reinstall the libc package in your Ubuntu Terminal.

Comment: Thanks @J_F for your comment. I used `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libc6-dev` to update `libc. However, the problem still persist. Any thoughts.

Comment: This is not a question but a bug report. Please submit it to the appropriate place, i.e., the lme4 bug tracker. You might want to show a minimal example too. PS: Why do you use a 32-bit OS?

Comment: there have been reports of problems with the latest `Matrix` package on 32-bit OS's.  Can you try *downgrading* Matrix?

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker for your useful comment. I downgraded Matrix and every thing works fine. Would appreciate if you change your comment to answer for future reference. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been reports of problems with the latest Matrix package, 1.2-8, on 32-bit OS's (personal communication from Terry Therneau and Brian Ripley). A fix <s>is probably on its way</s> may take a while (personal communication, M. Maechler), so I would try downgrading Matrix to version 1.2-7, e.g. `devtools::install_version("Matrix","1.2-7")` (you'll need to have compilation tools installed).

Looking at the [NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/news.html) for Matrix, I suspect this has something to do with:

> - C-API: SuiteSparse_long is now defined as int64_t on all platforms, and we now include (C99) ‘inttypes.h’

Comment: Yes, this had something to do with the API change (which also was needed for things to work correctly on some 32bit platforms !!)  as we (Dirk and I, maintainers of `RcppEigen` and `Matrix` respectively) had not been aware that  `RcppEigen` has a header file which had been more or less copy-pasted from Matrix... and that part had now become outdated and in conflict (on 32-bit Windows at least). Do update the 2 packages to the latest version

Comment: Can you give recommended package versions (i.e. everything should be OK if you have `Matrix` >= 1.2.8 and `RcppEigen` >= 0.3.2.9.1 ?)

Answer (score 2):

In the time the problem has been diagnosed and solved by me (the maintainer of `Matrix`):

Matrix 1.2-8 had updated its API, but `RcppEigen` had copied part of Matrix's C API (headers etc)... and now was no longer compatible...  on 32-bit only.

In the mean time, `RcppEigen` has been updated (and Matrix too).
Please install the latest versions of these two and all such `lme4` problems should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

May have been an issue with Ubuntu update. I had the same issue, but after the latest update to Ubuntu base the problem was fixed.

Comment: Thanks @user7644226 for your answer. I updated `Ubuntu`, however, the problem still persist. Any thoughts.