# lmerTest:::anova uses lazy loading of data sets?

Tags: r, lme4, lmertest

Ran into this problem while trying to get the empirical distribution of the K-R degrees of freedom...

This seems like fairly dangerous behaviour? Does it constitute a bug?

Reproducible example:

```
## import lmerTest package
library(lmerTest)

## an object of class merModLmerTest
m <- lmer(Informed.liking ~ Gender+Information+Product +(1|Consumer), data=ham)

# simulate data from fitted model
simData=ham
simData$Informed.liking=unlist(simulate(m))
# fit model to simulated data
m1 <- lmer(Informed.liking ~ Gender+Information+Product +(1|Consumer), data=simData)
stats:::anova(m1)
lmerTest:::anova(m1)

# simulate again, WITHOUT refitting
simData$Informed.liking=unlist(simulate(m))
stats:::anova(m1) # same as before
lmerTest:::anova(m1) # not same as before!
```

Answer (score 0):

my response does not constitute a solid answer, rather an extended comment:
this looks pretty bad - in fact I have discovered today that almost all the analyses that I conducted in a project that was on the verge of submission have to be redone because of a related behavior of `lmerTest`.
The problem I have run into was when I used a short function that fits a model with `lmer` and then returns `coef(summary(model))` - simple stuff, two lines of code. However the input to this function was named `data` and I also had a dataframe called `data` in the workspace. It seems that although during fitting with `lmer` the local variable from the function scope was correctly used, during `summary` the workspace `data` variable was used (which often was not the same as the dataframe passed to the function) leading to invalid t values and degrees of freedom leading to incorrect p values (the estimates and their standard error was ok however).
So, answering your question:

> This seems like fairly dangerous behaviour? Does it constitute a bug?

It seems dangerous indeed and I would definitelly call this a bug.